# NextAuth sign out function not working after app restart - how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am using this setup for my app: Prisma + PostgreSQL ( running in docker containers ), with NextJs ( app directory ), NextAuth for authentication.
I noticed that after restarting my app if a user had previously signed in he would not be able to logout correctly after the app is running again. I noticed that the cookie `next-auth.session-token` does not get cleared when I run the signOut function that NextAuth provides.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Sign in with a user
2. Close the app
3. Start the app again
4. Try to logout

Here are my authOptions

```
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs';
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { prisma } from '../../prisma/prisma';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Sign in',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'example@example.com',
        },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user || !(await compare(credentials.password, user.password))) {
          return null;
        }

        return {
          id: user.id,
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      console.warn('Session Callback', { session, token });
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          userId: token.id,
        },
      };
    },
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      console.warn('JWT Callback', { token, user });
      if (user) {
        // const u = user as unknown as any;
        return {
          ...token,
          id: user.id,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};
```

And here is my button that signs the user out :

```
'use client';

import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react';

interface Props {
  className?: string;
  children?: JSX.Element | string;
}

export const SignOutButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ className, children }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => signOut()} className={className}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

I can see that the function gets executed because my page reloads, but it does not clrear the cookies for some reason. It only happens when I restart the app.

Comment: Having the same issue, only the app doesnt even have to restart.

Comment: same here.. any news?